# How to check that a function is solution of an ODE with Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations

Let $$S(t)=\int_0^t\int_t^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{1/4}(y-x)^{\frac{3}{2}}}-\frac{1}{(1+y^2)^{\frac{1}{4}}(y-x)^\frac{3}{2}}\right)\mathrm d y\mathrm d x.$$

Is there a way to check with Mathematica that the functions $$u(x)=C(\mu^2+(x-x_0)^2)^{-\frac{1}{4}}$$
are solution of the ODE
$$-\left(\frac{(1+t^2)^{\frac{5}{4}}}{t}u'(t)\mathcal S(t)\right)'-Cu^3=0\ \ ?$$

I tried in the brute force way, but it's very long to compute and it doesn't work. Here is my Mathematica code :

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

If it's not possible to compute it in general, is there a way to have a numerical approximation of

$$-\left(\frac{(1+t^2)^{\frac{5}{4}}}{t}u'(t)\mathcal S(t)\right)'-Cu^3=0$$
when $$u(x)=C(\mu^2+(x-x_0)^2)^{-\frac{1}{4}} \ \ ?$$

**Here full code**

```
In[1]:= S[t_] := 
 Integrate[
  1/((1 + x^2)^(1/4) (y - x)^(3/2)) - 
   1/((1 + y^2)^(1/4) (y - x)^(3/2)), {x, 0, t}, {y, t, Infinity}]

In[2]:= u[x_] := (1 + x^2)^(-1/4)

In[6]:= K[x_] := D[((1 + t^2)^(5/4)/t)*u'[x]*S[t], t]

In[7]:= K[x]/(u[x]^3)


During evaluation of In[7]:= Refine::fas: Warning: one or more assumptions evaluated to False.

Out[7]= (1 + x^2)^(
 3/4) (-(1/(2 t (1 + x^2)^(5/4)))(1 + t^2)^(5/4) x \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(t\), \
\(\[Infinity]\)]If[\((\((Re[t] != 
               0 && \((\((Im[y] >= 0 && Im[t] <= 0)\) || 
\*FractionBox[\(Im[y]\), \(Im[t]\)] >= 1 ||
```

Comment: Please post your mathematica code (not an image )

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your warning message following In[7]...

Comment: Note that capital `K` has a special meaning in Mathematica.